# OCaml Toplevel Mode Returns <obj> instead of the object

Tags: ocaml

I'm currently using OCaml in Toplevel mode and often when I'm trying to get an output, the Toplevel Mode returns `<obj>` instead of the object I'm trying to see. How can I tell OCaml to show me the actual object instead of just `<obj>` ?

Comment: Can you give an example of interaction where you don't like the output of the toplevel?

Comment: @Thomash See my comment to the answer. I'm using a software written in O'Caml and I'm trying to print the information inside an object, which has a quite complicated type:  (int * CGC.lcrs_ketket) list * (((int * CGC.ket) list * ((int * int) * int Alg.lcrs_vector) list) * ((int * int) * Alg.lcrs_field) list) where the non-standard names appearing here are classes defined by the program.

Answer (score 3):

The toplevel is treating objects as abstract values, as you see. To get more information you'll have to write your own print function for the type and install it using `#install_printer`.

```
# object method getv = 14 end;;
- : < getv : int > = <obj>

# let p f x = Format.fprintf f "<< v = %d >>" x#getv;;
val p : Format.formatter -> < getv : int; .. > -> unit = <fun>
# #install_printer p;;

# object method getv = 14 end;;
- : < getv : int > = << v = 14 >>
```

Notes

- This requires getter methods for the values you're interested in. There's no way to access the fields of an object from outside.
- Print functions are called based on *types*. OCaml object typing is structural (based on methods and their types) rather than nominal (based on a hierarchy of names established by the programmer).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm completely new to O'Caml and your example, although the object is simple, is a bit hard for me to understand. I'm trying to use a software called CleGo that computes Clebsch-Gordan coefficients. At some point in the computation I get an object of type: 
         (int * CGC.lcrs_ketket) list *
         (((int * CGC.ket) list * ((int * int) * int Alg.lcrs_vector) list) *
          ((int * int) * Alg.lcrs_field) list)
    where the non-standard names appearing here are classes defined by the program. I'm trying to print this object or some part of it.

Comment: Yow, that is complicated! If you want to see inside the objects from toplevel you'll need to code up some print functions like I show above, one for each class you care about. To be honest I often just add prints directly to the code I'm interested in. But I am old school.